# Let $\varphi: G\rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism. Show that for each $a \in G$, $| \varphi (a) | \le | a |$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

> Let $(G,*)$ and $(G',\circ)$ be groups.  The order of an element $x$ of a group is denoted by $|x|$.  Let $\varphi: G\rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism. Show that, for each $a \in G$, $$\big| \varphi (a) \big| \le | a |\,.$$

I thought so, if $\varphi$ is a homomorphism then given $a, b \in G$, we have
\begin{equation}
\varphi (a \ast b) = \varphi (a) \diamond \varphi (b).
\end{equation}

I don't know how to use this to show that the order of an element in the image is less than or equal to the order of that element. Can someone help me please?

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or what you've tried would be a big step forward!

Comment: Look, if you are not going to help in the matter do not post these harmless comments. If it will not help, it does not answer, simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: We have $a^{|a|} = 1$, hence $1=\varphi(1) = \varphi(a^{|a|}) = \varphi(a)^{|a|}$. What can you conclude about $|\varphi(a)|?$

Comment: I found you ... So I didn't really understand your tip. Like I need to show that the order of $f(a)$ is less than the order of a. I know that $|f(a) |$ means $f(a)^n = e$ ($n$ is the order of $f(a)$) and $a^m = e$ ($m$ is the order of $a$).

Comment: Do you know the following theorem: If $G$ is a group, $g\in G$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$ then $g^n = 1 \iff |g|$ divides $n$?

Comment: If you apply this with $1= \varphi(a)^{|a|}$, then you find that $|\varphi(a)|$ divides $|a|$, by the hint in my answer. In particular, $|\varphi(a)| \leq |a|$.

Comment: I didn't know that theorem. Saying $|\varphi(a)|$ divides $|a|$ means saying that $|a|=|\varphi(a)|\cdot x$, with $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. Now I understand, I just need to prove this theorem or read the proof of it. Let me ask you, I couldn’t understand where you vote the question, this site is a little difficult to handle :(

Comment: Maybe you don't have enough reputation yet to vote, but I think you have enough reputation to accept the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can you help me with this?. Show that the composition of submersions is also a submersion.

Be g,h submersions so we need to show that g∘h is a submersion, that is, we need to show that D(g∘h) is overjetora. But who is D(g∘h)? By the rule of Chain D(g∘h)=Dg(h)⋅Dh. By the hypothesis we know that g,h are submersions, so Dg and Dh are superjetoras. My doubt is just need to show that the product of linear transformations overjetoras are overjetora (Dg(h)⋅Dh) ? Another thing the derivative of g applied to h influences not being overjetora since g and h are. Can someone help me please. Thanks.

Comment: @FernandaDuarte What is overjetora?

Comment: Means sobrejetora.

Comment: Can you help me on this one please?

Comment: Sorry that's no english

Comment: But you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @FernandaDuarte I'm sorry no I don't.

Comment: Mean surjection.

Comment: The composition of surjections is again a surjection. Does that help?

Comment: I need to show that the two-function product surjection is surjection. Can you help me on this one please?

Comment: Show that the two-function product surjection is surjection.

Solution. (What I tried) Be $g$ and $h$ surjection functions. If $g: A \rightarrow B$ is surjection then for all $y \in B$ there is $x \in A$ such that $y=g(x)$. Similarly, if $h: B \rightarrow C$ is surjection then for all $z \in C$ there is $w \in B$ such that $z=h(w)$. But I need to show that my function $k(x)=g(x)\cdot h(x)$ is surjection. Can someone help me please?

Comment: The product is composition, not pointwise.

Comment: not really, it's a product (multiplication) even.

Comment: It just got weird. I don't know, i don't know I'm thinking

Comment: In the chain rule it is a composition. For pointwise products this is false: Consider $f=g:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}:x \mapsto x$ which is a surjection yet $fg$ is not surjective because $-1$ is not in the image.

Answer (score 1):

By induction, show that $\varphi(a^n) = \varphi(a)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$. Hence
$$1_{G'} = \varphi(1_G) = \varphi(a^{|a|}) = \varphi(a)^{|a|}$$
and then...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You have a surjective morphism from $\langle\mkern 2mu a\mkern2mu\rangle$ onto $\langle\, \varphi(a)\,\rangle$.